# Convert Array of DataFrames to Single DataFrame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, multiprocessing

**TLDR:** I don't know how to take an array of DataFrames and build a MultiIndex around it.

**TLDR 2:** From my research, it is recommended to deal with the return result than to try to work off of a global/single/shared DataFrame in `Pool().Map()`. If somebody has a way to share it, I'm all for it.

---

I am trying to merge an array of [MultiIndex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html) Pandas DataFrames that have been returned by a [Pool()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).[Map()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map) function.

```
p = Pool()
results = p.map(run_experiment, experiment_collection)
```

`Pool().map()` returns as an array. Let's say the process returns the array with 1000 `DataFrame` with a first index of `[0:5]` and second `[0:50]`.

What I want is to create a final output that is a single DataFrame that would separate each experiment so `[0:1000]` / `[0:5]` /`[0:50]`.

---

I know how to create the MultiIndex using `np.zeros_like` and then fill the DataFrame, but I don't know how to take an array of DataFrames and build a MultiIndex around it.

```
rounds = range(0,1000)
levels = [... some set of levels ...]
labels = [... some set of labels ...]
iterables = [rounds, labels, levels]

names = ['round', 'label', 'values']
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables, names=names)

index_names = [... some set of index names...]
empty_df = pd.DataFrame(
              np.zeros_like(np.random.randn(5, 50000)),
              index=index_names,
              columns=index
             )
             .sort_index()
             .sort_index(axis=1)
```

---

In my first example, `results` is an array of MultiIndex DataFrame of `levels` / `labels`. What I am trying to do is create a final DataFrame that replaces the top level (an array holding all these DataFrames) as just a new index.

When I try

```
p = Pool()
results = pd.DataFrame(
              p.map(run_experiment, experiment_collection),
              index=index_names,
              columns=index
             )
             .sort_index()
             .sort_index(axis=1)
```

I am getting `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 1000), indices imply (shape of intended index)`, which makes sense because it is an array of 1000 DataFrames.

If I concatenate (which feels like the better way to go)

```
results = pd.concat(p.map(run_experiment, experiment_collection))
```

I get a DataFrame with `levels` / `labels`, but no `round`.

```
iterables = [rounds, labels, levels]
```

---

```
pd.concat(objs, axis=0, join='outer', join_axes=None, ignore_index=False,
       keys=None, levels=None, names=None, verify_integrity=False)
```

I'm not sure what of the options (keys, levels, names) I should be manipulating here to get my `rounds` back into the DataFrame.

```
results = pd.concat(
              p.map(run_experiment, experiment_collection),
              levels=iterables,
              names=names,
              axis=1
          )
```

Gets me really close to the format I want, but no `round`.

---

I can get more specific if I need to, but not entirely sure what else would be helpful in getting to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Lacking a better answer, I am recreating my original DataFrame, and iterating through the returned result from `Pool().Map()`, inserting each list position into the DataFrame. Seems there has to be a better way, but I can't think of it.

```
p = Pool()
results = p.map(run_experiment, experiment_collection)

final_df = pd.DataFrame(
            np.zeros_like(np.random.randn(5, 50000)),
            index=index_names,
            columns=index
           )
           .sort_index()
           .sort_index(axis=1)

for result in results:
  final_df[increment_value] = result
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several good ways to do this:

1) If you are starting with a bunch of Series objects :
    You set the series objects name parameter to be a tuple. Then use pd.concat([series list], axis=1)

2) If you have a single level map of dataframes, you can use the fact that pd.concat can accept a dict as its first argument. E.g.

```
pd.concat({A:df1, B:df2}, axis=1)
```

will create a multilevel index with A, B as the top level and the columns of your df as the second level.Although you cannot nest dicts, you can do this multiple times to build an index of arbitary depth.

3) You can use the Dataframe constructor on a DF but pass a list of tuples as the column names. E.f. if you have a df with columns A,B and you do df_new = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=[("Foo","A"), ("Foo","B")]) and this will create a new df with a multilevel index, you can do this for your df's individually and then concatenate them. Pandas will appropriately concatenate two dataframes with indexes with the same number of levels.